# New-SMBShare on non English system

Tags: powershell, internationalization

When i try to create share using PowerShell on a Spanish system with following command:

`New-SMBShare -Name 'scripts$' -Path 'c:\scripts' -ChangeAccess Everyone`

I get an error which translates into:

`New-SMBShare: No mapping was made between account names and security identifiers.`

Because it expects `Todos` group instead of `Everyone`.

Is there a way to have one `New-SmbShare` command for all localizations?

Comment: You'll need to resolve the identity of the `Everyone` well-known SID manually: `[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid,$null).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Nice, added a proper answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Everyone` identity is known as a "Well-known" Security Identifier.

You can construct and translate it to the localized representation like this:

```
$EveryoneWKSID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null)
$EveryoneLocal = $EveryoneWKSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

At which point you can do:

```
New-SMBShare -Name 'scripts$' -Path 'c:\scripts' -ChangeAccess $EveryoneLocal
```